# The view acc_app.views.merchant_messages didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Here I'm creating a chat system between merchants and admin, but every time I send a message via form it's showing this error.

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/merchant-dashboard/messages/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'acc_app', # app
 'widget_tweaks',
 'rest_framework']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 186, in _get_response
    self.check_response(response, callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 307, in check_response
    raise ValueError(

Exception Type: ValueError at /merchant-dashboard/messages/
Exception Value: The view acc_app.views.merchant_messages didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

**MyCode**

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def message_list(request, receiver=None):

    ....
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # message = request.POST['message']
        # admin = UserAccount.objects.get(is_superuser=True)
        # send_message = Message.objects.create(sender=request.user, receiver=admin, message=message)
        # send_message.save()
        serializer = MessageSerializer(data=request)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


@login_required(login_url='login-user')
def merchant_messages(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        message_list(request, receiver=request.user)
        admin = UserAccount.objects.get(is_superuser=True)
        all_messages = {
            'receiver': UserAccount.objects.get(email=admin),
            'messages': Message.objects.filter(sender=admin, receiver=request.user) |
            Message.objects.filter(sender=request.user, receiver=admin)
        }

        return render(request, 'dashboard/merchant/message-task.html', all_messages)
```

HTML file

```
<form method="POST" id="chat-box">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="input-group">
         <input name="message" typetype="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Message"/>                       
         <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">SEND</button>
          </span>
     </div>
</form>
```

It works fine to show the received messages, but can't send any message.
I also tried to use *Message.objects.create()* and the same error showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your HTML form does a post request to the URL linked to the `merchant_messages` view, instead of the `messages_list` view.

The error you're receiving indicates that no HttpResponse is received from the `merchant_messages` view, which is correct since you only return a correct response when the view receives a GET request.

You should change your HTML form to make the post to the url bound to the `messages_list` view (and maybe change the name  of the view since it creates a message, not list them.

**Tip**: next time also post your urls.py so we can have a look at how you linked your urls to your views.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a POST request to view which does not handle POST requests at all.

```
@login_required(login_url='login-user')
def merchant_messages(request):

    // missing here
    // if request.method == "POST":


    if request.method == "GET":
        message_list(request, receiver=request.user)
        admin = UserAccount.objects.get(is_superuser=True)
        all_messages = {
            'receiver': UserAccount.objects.get(email=admin),
            'messages': Message.objects.filter(sender=admin, receiver=request.user) |
            Message.objects.filter(sender=request.user, receiver=admin)
        }

        return render(request, 'dashboard/merchant/message-task.html', all_messages)
```